# Non Equi-Join on a time series table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables a and b. A contains start dates and end dates whereas table b contains 10 min bins with values associated to each bin:

```
a
StartDate            EndDate
2018-03-06 10:13:00  2018-03-06 10:45:00

b
TimeStamp / Amount
2018-03-06 10:10:00 / 100
2018-03-06 10:20:00 / 89
2018-03-06 10:30:00 / 50
2018-03-06 10:40:00 / 78
```

The **result** I'd like to acheive is this:

```
a.StartDate / a.EndDate / b.Amount  
2018-03-06 10:13:00 / 2018-03-06 10:45:00 / 248.0

where b.Amount is equal to = 0.7 * 100 + 89 + 50 + 0.5 * 78
```

I've started the below query but it's not giving me any results:

```
SELECT a.StartDate, a.EndDate, b.Amount
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.StartDate > b.TimeStamp
       AND a.EndDate < DATEADD(mm,10,b.TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is incorrect.  It is excluding all rows since `TimeStamp` can never be before the start date *and* after the end date.  Change it to:

```
JOIN b ON a.StartDate < b.TimeStamp
       AND a.EndDate > DATEADD(mm,10,b.TimeStamp)
```

Also, don't use the contraction, `mm` to indicate `MINUTE` (it actually indicates `MONTH`!).  See [this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql#arguments) for details.  Use `MINUTE`:

```
JOIN b ON a.StartDate < b.TimeStamp
       AND a.EndDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, b.TimeStamp)
```

To get a calculated total amount, you'll need to use the `SUM()` aggregate:

```
SELECT a.StartDate
    , a.EndDate
    , TotalAmount = SUM(b.Amount)
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.StartDate < b.TimeStamp
       AND a.EndDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, b.TimeStamp)
GROUP BY a.StartDate
    , a.EndDate;
```

Pro-rating the start and end amounts, as you appear to indicate in your question, might be accomplished like this:

```
SELECT a.StartDate
    , a.EndDate
    , b.TimeStamp
    , b.Amount
    , ProRatedAmount = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.StartDate, b.TimeStamp) < 0 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.StartDate, b.TimeStamp) > -10
            THEN b.Amount - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.TimeStamp, a.StartDate) / 10.0 * b.Amount)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.EndDate, b.TimeStamp) < 0 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.EndDate, b.TimeStamp) > -10
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.TimeStamp, a.EndDate) / 10.0 * b.Amount
        ELSE b.Amount
        END
FROM a
    JOIN b ON DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, a.StartDate) < b.TimeStamp
       AND b.TimeStamp < DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, a.EndDate);
```

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════╦════════════════╗
║        StartDate        ║         EndDate         ║        TimeStamp        ║ Amount ║ ProRatedAmount ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2018-03-06 10:13:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:45:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:10:00.000 ║    100 ║      70.000000 ║
║ 2018-03-06 10:13:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:45:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:20:00.000 ║     89 ║      89.000000 ║
║ 2018-03-06 10:13:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:45:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:30:00.000 ║     50 ║      50.000000 ║
║ 2018-03-06 10:13:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:45:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:40:00.000 ║     78 ║      39.000000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════╩════════════════╝
```

Aggregating those amounts into a total might be accomplished with a CTE:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
SELECT a.StartDate
    , a.EndDate
    , Amount = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.StartDate, b.TimeStamp) < 0 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.StartDate, b.TimeStamp) > -10
            THEN b.Amount - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.TimeStamp, a.StartDate) / 10.0 * b.Amount)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.EndDate, b.TimeStamp) < 0 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.EndDate, b.TimeStamp) > -10
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.TimeStamp, a.EndDate) / 10.0 * b.Amount
        ELSE b.Amount
        END
FROM a
    JOIN b ON DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, a.StartDate) < b.TimeStamp
       AND b.TimeStamp < DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, a.EndDate)
)
SELECT src.StartDate
    , src.EndDate
    , Amount = SUM(src.Amount)
FROM src
GROUP BY src.StartDate
    , src.EndDate
ORDER BY src.StartDate
    , src.EndDate;
```

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╗
║        StartDate        ║         EndDate         ║   Amount   ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2018-03-06 10:13:00.000 ║ 2018-03-06 10:45:00.000 ║ 248.000000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a less cumbersome solution is possible.

With the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE periods
    ([start] datetime,
     [end] datetime) ;
INSERT INTO periods
    ([start], [end])
VALUES
    ('2018-03-06 10:13:00',  '2018-03-06 10:45:00'),
    ('2018-03-06 09:45:00',  '2018-03-06 10:13:00'),
    ('2018-03-06 10:45:00',  '2018-03-06 11:13:00') ;
create table bins ([bindate] datetime, [quantity] smallint);
insert into bins ([bindate],[quantity]) values
('2018-03-06 10:10:00', 100),
('2018-03-06 10:20:00', 89),
('2018-03-06 10:30:00', 50),
('2018-03-06 10:40:00', 78) ;
```

the problem can be solved as follows:

```
select s3.start, s3.[end], sum(s3.part) part from (
 select s2.start, s2.[end], s2.quantity, s2.bin_from,
        datediff(SECOND,s2.time_from,s2.time_to) span,
        s2.quantity * datediff(SECOND,s2.time_from,s2.time_to) / 600  part
 from (
  select s.*,
      case when s.bin_from < s.start
           then s.start else s.bin_from end time_from,
      case when s.[end] < s.bin_to
           then s.[end] else s.bin_to end time_to
  from (
    SELECT p.*,
           b.[bindate] bin_from,
           DATEADD(MINUTE,10,b.[bindate]) bin_to,
           b.[quantity]
     from periods p, bins b
     where b.[bindate] <= p.[end]
       and DATEADD(MINUTE,10,b.[bindate]) >= p.[start]
   ) s
  ) s2
 ) s3
group by s3.start, s3.[end];
```

giving

```
2018-03-06T09:45:00Z    2018-03-06T10:13:00Z    30
2018-03-06T10:13:00Z    2018-03-06T10:45:00Z    248
2018-03-06T10:45:00Z    2018-03-06T11:13:00Z    39
```

See for yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db4e5/24